# Share button from Google+ in emails

Tags: email, button, google-plus, share

I want to use the Google+ share button in a HTML-mail. Is it possible?
I tried to put the hyperlink of the share-button into the email. It is working with Facebook but not with Google+.
Please tell me how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You want the [share link feature](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink) but probably without the javascript snippet.

`https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}`

Comment: I tried the Hyperlink, but there is a Problem with the GET-data. If I put ?variable=name in the URL Google+ doesn't take it.